# serve a page without changing the URL on address bar .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [L,P]
```

this is what I have but when I hit my.domain.com/folder it changes the URL to domain.com/folder.
I would like the domain name to not change on the address bar.
any ideas/help ? I tried different other options that I googled but none of them seemed to work they all behave the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't serve content from a different domain without the browser changing the address if you use RewriteRule. The only thing you could do is use a reverse proxy, but that adds quite some overhead to your site, so I would recommend against that.
The easiest way to solve this is to add another `VirtualHost` to your apache configuration that listens to my.domain.com and point to the same root directory as domain.com.
Make sure you don't get penalties for duplicate content when you do this.

Comment: its for api calls no content will be served so that would be fine. Thanks @scallioXTX